# Daemon in python generates defunct/zombie linux process

Tags: python, daemon, zombie-process, python-daemon, defunct

I'm trying to spawn long processes from a flask application. So I have a main process that handles incoming web requests and from which I start daemons using the python-daemon library. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import os
import time
import daemon
import lockfile

def daemon_function():
    return True

working_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
pid_file = os.path.join(working_directory,"my_daemon.pid")

daemon_context = daemon.DaemonContext(
        working_directory=working_directory,
        pidfile=lockfile.FileLock(pid_file),
    )

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    with daemon_context:
        daemon_function()

time.sleep(10)
```

When I use the linux command `ps -ef` while the main process is still running, after the daemon process has terminated, I see this output:

```
user     2484     1  0 09:38 ?        00:00:01 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
user    11269  6061  0 12:07 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
user    28817 11269  1 15:43 pts/2    00:00:00 python test_daemon.py
user    28818 28817  0 15:43 pts/2    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
```

The reason why I use the fork function before the `with daemon_context:` statement is that I need the main process to continue.

Should I worry about the created defunct process (I might spawn a lot of them) ? How could I avoid this zombie to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create zombie processes you should wait for them to finish i.e. execute wait system call instead of sleep:

```
import os
import time
import daemon
import lockfile

def daemon_function():
    return True

working_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
pid_file = os.path.join(working_directory,"my_daemon.pid")

daemon_context = daemon.DaemonContext(
        working_directory=working_directory,
        pidfile=lockfile.FileLock(pid_file),
    )

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    with daemon_context:
        daemon_function()

os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

Comment: Hum right, that was mush easier than I expected :-). You can actually let the last line time.sleep(10) in the end, which represent some kind of infinite loop. Since the parent pid doesn't do anything, the last os.waitpid(pid, 0) in instantly reached. Thx